# Custom React-native Hook runs the component that calls it twice. I don't understand why

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await, react-hooks, aws-amplify

I am trying to learn to work with custom Hooks in React-native. I am using AWS Amplify as my backend, and it has a method to get the authenticated user's information, namely the `Auth.currentUserInfo` method. However, what it returns is an object and I want to make a custom Hook to both returns the part of the object that I need, and also abstract away this part of my code from the visualization part. I have a component called `App`, and a custom Hook called `useUserId`. The code for them is as follows:

The `useUserId` Hook:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";

const getUserInfo = async () => {
  try {
    const userInfo = await Auth.currentUserInfo();
    const userId = userInfo?.attributes?.sub;
    return userId;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Failed to get the  AuthUserId", e);
  }
};

const useUserId = () => {
  const [id, setId] = useState("");
  const userId = getUserInfo();

  useEffect(() => {
    userId.then((userId) => {
      setId(userId);
    });
  }, [userId]);

  return id;
};

export default useUserId;
```

The `App` component:

```js
import React from "react";
import useUserId from "../custom-hooks/UseUserId";

const App = () => {
  const authUserId = useUserId();
  console.log(authUserId);
```

However, when I try to run the App component, I get the same Id written on the screen twice,  meaning that the `App` component is executed again.

The problem with this is that I am using this custom Hook in another custom Hook, let's call it `useFetchData` that fetches some data based on the userId, then each time this is executed that is also re-executed, which causes some problems.

I am kind of new to React, would you please guide me on what I am doing wrong here, and what is the solution to this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely due to the fact that you've declared `userId` in the hook body. When `useUserId` is called in the `App` component it declares `userId` and updates state. This triggers a rerender and `userId` is declared again, and updates the state again, this time with the same value. The `useState` hook being updated to the same value a second time quits the loop.

[Bailing out of a state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update)

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state,
> React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects.
> (React uses the [Object.is comparison algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Description).)

Either move `const userId = getUserInfo();` out of the `useUserId` hook

```
const userId = getUserInfo();

const useUserId = () => {
  const [id, setId] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    userId.then((userId) => {
      setId(userId);
    });
  }, []);

  return id;
};
```

or more it into the `useEffect` callback body.

```
const useUserId = () => {
  const [id, setId] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserInfo().then((userId) => {
      setId(userId);
    });
  }, []);

  return id;
};
```

and in both cases remove `userId` as a dependency of the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed explanation @Drew Reese, I have a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70515985/how-to-use-a-custom-hook-that-returns-a-value-inside-another-custom-hook) it would be so kind of you if you could please also take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Replace userId.then with to getUserId().then. It doesn't make sense to have the result of getUserId in the body of a component, since it's a promise and that code will be run every time the component renders.